# Google Sheets-Script function increment could not be found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am able to run the following function from the script editor.  However, when I try to assign it to a button in my google sheet, I get the error code:

> "Script function increment could not be found."

Any ideas!? I have tried refreshing the page, copying and pasting the function name for accuracy, etc.

```
function increment(){

var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B7");

var cellValue = cell.getValue();
cell.setValue(cellValue + 1)

}
```

Comment: Hi, here is a link I found where they were getting the same issue and base on the answers how it was fixed. I hope this help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334378/google-sheets-script-function-could-not-be-found

Comment: could you share your spreadsheet or the full code, by the way you are trying to increment a string imagine you have `var string = "hello" + 1` you get `string = "hello1"`.